# Keras Custom loss Penalize more when actual and prediction are on opposite sides of Zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, mse

I'm training a model to predict percentage change in prices. Both MSE and RMSE are giving me up to 99% accuracy but when I check how often both actual and prediction are pointing in the same direction `((actual >0 and pred > 0) or (actual < 0 and pred < 0))`, I get about 49%.

Please how do I define a custom loss that penalizes opposite directions very heavily. I'd also like to add a slight penalty for when the predictions exceeds the actual in a given direction.

So

- `actual = 0.1 and pred = -0.05` should be penalized a lot more than `actual = 0.1 and pred = 0.05`,
- and `actual = 0.1 and pred = 0.15` slightly more penalty than `actual = 0.1 and pred = 0.05`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave it up to you to define your exact logic, but here is how you can implement what you want with `tf.cond`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = [[0.1]]
y_pred = [[0.05]]
mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  penalty = 20

  # actual = 0.1 and pred = -0.05 should be penalized a lot more than actual = 0.1 and pred = 0.05
  loss = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(tf.greater(y_true, 0.0), tf.less(y_pred, 0.0)),
                   lambda: mse(y_true, y_pred) * penalty,
                   lambda: mse(y_true, y_pred) * penalty / 4)
  
  #actual = 0.1 and pred = 0.15 slightly more penalty than actual = 0.1 and pred = 0.05
  loss = tf.cond(tf.greater(y_pred, y_true),
                   lambda: loss * penalty / 2,
                   lambda: loss * penalty / 3)
  return loss 
  
print(custom_loss(y_true, y_pred))
```

Comment: Hi +AloneTogether, I'm getting this error and I don't know how to resolve it: ```InvalidArgumentError:  The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [64]
  [[{{node gradient_tape/CustomLoss/cond_1/StatelessIf/gradient_tape/CustomLoss/weighted_loss/Mul/_30}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_67529]

Function call stack:
train_function```

Comment: Can you maybe post a new question with your error and relevant code ?

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69809867/custom-loss-function-returning-invalidargumenterror-the-second-input-must-be